# spigot 1.13 enabling worldguard crashes dynmap from showing faction grounds

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

i run a spigot (bukkit minecraft) server on linux, with these plugins:
https://pasteboard.co/Ib1vdCE.png

factions work fine on dynmap, a live map that shows faction territory, but when i enable worldguard, i get these errors and the dynmap doesnt update anymore.

Errors while booting server: 
https://pasteboard.co/Ib1wXia.png (same but screenshot)

```
[14:52:07 INFO]: [WorldGuard] Enabling WorldGuard v7.0.0-beta-03;e51a220
[14:52:07 INFO]: [WorldGuard] (world) TNT ignition is PERMITTED.
[14:52:07 INFO]: [WorldGuard] (world) Lighters are PERMITTED.
[14:52:07 INFO]: [WorldGuard] (world) Lava fire is blocked.
[14:52:07 INFO]: [WorldGuard] (world) Fire spread is UNRESTRICTED.
[14:52:07 INFO]: [WorldGuard] Loaded configuration for world 'world'
[14:52:07 INFO]: [WorldGuard] (world_nether) TNT ignition is PERMITTED.
[14:52:07 INFO]: [WorldGuard] (world_nether) Lighters are PERMITTED.
[14:52:07 INFO]: [WorldGuard] (world_nether) Lava fire is blocked.
[14:52:07 INFO]: [WorldGuard] (world_nether) Fire spread is UNRESTRICTED.
[14:52:07 INFO]: [WorldGuard] Loaded configuration for world 'world_nether'
[14:52:07 INFO]: [WorldGuard] (world_the_end) TNT ignition is PERMITTED.
[14:52:07 INFO]: [WorldGuard] (world_the_end) Lighters are PERMITTED.
[14:52:07 INFO]: [WorldGuard] (world_the_end) Lava fire is blocked.
[14:52:07 INFO]: [WorldGuard] (world_the_end) Fire spread is UNRESTRICTED.
[14:52:07 INFO]: [WorldGuard] Loaded configuration for world 'world_the_end'
[14:52:08 INFO]: [WorldGuard] Loading region data...
[14:52:08 INFO]: [Factions] Enabling Factions v2.14.0
[14:52:08 INFO]: [Factions 2.14.0] === ENABLE START ===
[14:52:08 INFO]: [ClearLag] No updates found!
[14:52:08 INFO]: [Factions 2.14.0] Integration Activated IntegrationV18
[14:52:08 INFO]: [Factions 2.14.0] Integration Activated IntegrationV19
[14:52:08 INFO]: [Factions 2.14.0] Integration Activated IntegrationSpigot
[14:52:08 INFO]: [Factions 2.14.0] === ENABLE COMPLETE (Took 812ms) ===
[14:52:08 INFO]: [EssentialsXMPP] Enabling EssentialsXMPP v2.16.1.0
[14:52:08 WARN]: config broken for xmpp
[14:52:08 INFO]: [EssentialsProtect] Enabling EssentialsProtect v2.16.1.0
[14:52:08 INFO]: [EssentialsProtect] Continuing to enable Protect.
[14:52:08 INFO]: [Dynmap-Factions] Enabling Dynmap-Factions v0.90-39
[14:52:08 INFO]: [Dynmap-Factions] initializing
[14:52:08 INFO]: [Dynmap-Factions] Dynmap does not have player-info-protected en                      abled - visibility-by-faction will have no effect
[14:52:08 INFO]: [Dynmap-Factions] version 0.90-39 is activated
[14:52:08 INFO]: Server permissions file permissions.yml is empty, ignoring it
[14:52:09 INFO]: Done (7.983s)! For help, type "help"
[14:52:10 INFO]: [dynmap] Loading default resource pack
[14:52:11 WARN]: [Dynmap-Factions] Task #44 for Dynmap-Factions v0.90-39 generat                      ed an exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at java.lang.String.replace(String.java:2240) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
        at org.dynmap.factions.DynmapFactionsPlugin.formatInfoWindow(DynmapFacti                      onsPlugin.java:207) ~[?:?]
        at org.dynmap.factions.DynmapFactionsPlugin.handleFactionOnWorld(DynmapF                      actionsPlugin.java:312) ~[?:?]
        at org.dynmap.factions.DynmapFactionsPlugin.updateFactions(DynmapFaction                      sPlugin.java:507) ~[?:?]
        at org.dynmap.factions.DynmapFactionsPlugin.access$000(DynmapFactionsPlu                      gin.java:49) ~[?:?]
        at org.dynmap.factions.DynmapFactionsPlugin$FactionsUpdate.run(DynmapFac                      tionsPlugin.java:133) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_13_R2.scheduler.CraftTask.run(CraftTask.jav                      a:81) ~[minecraft_server.jar:git-Spigot-518206a-a5b9c7b]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_13_R2.scheduler.CraftScheduler.mainThreadHe                      artbeat(CraftScheduler.java:391) [minecraft_server.jar:git-Spigot-518206a-a5b9c7                      b]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_13_R2.MinecraftServer.b(MinecraftServer.java:                      888) [minecraft_server.jar:git-Spigot-518206a-a5b9c7b]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_13_R2.DedicatedServer.b(DedicatedServer.java:                      417) [minecraft_server.jar:git-Spigot-518206a-a5b9c7b]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_13_R2.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:                      830) [minecraft_server.jar:git-Spigot-518206a-a5b9c7b]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_13_R2.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.jav                      a:728) [minecraft_server.jar:git-Spigot-518206a-a5b9c7b]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_191]
[14:52:14 INFO]:
[14:52:14 INFO]: ____----====[ Sponsored by ServerMiner ]====----____
[14:52:14 INFO]: Get 20% off a Premium Factions Server at ServerMiner:
[14:52:14 INFO]: https://ServerMiner.com/plugins/Factions-Server-Hosting?p=Massi                      veCraft
[14:52:14 INFO]:
[14:52:14 INFO]: Factions and MassiveCore is sponsored by ServerMiner.com!
[14:52:14 INFO]: They help us fund the development of new plugin features.
[14:52:14 INFO]:
[14:52:14 INFO]: Only server operators get this message, not regular players.
[14:52:14 INFO]: Type /mcore sponsor to disable it.
[14:52:14 INFO]:
[14:53:06 INFO]: UUID of player TheDarchrow is fb31996f-8cb7-4d9c-ab3f-5296b27e4aee
[14:53:07 INFO]: TheDarchrow[/109.245.37.100:64934] logged in with entity id 74 at ([world]1123.1225568526106, 117.0, 980.6999999880791)
[14:53:07 WARN]: [Essentials] Task #317 for Essentials v2.16.1.0 generated an exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.earth2me.essentials.xmpp.XMPPManager.updatePresence(XMPPManager.java:146) ~[?:?]
        at com.earth2me.essentials.xmpp.EssentialsXMPP.updatePresence(EssentialsXMPP.java:113) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_13_R2.scheduler.CraftTask.run(CraftTask.java:81) ~[minecraft_server.jar:git-Spigot-518206a-a5b9c7b]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_13_R2.scheduler.CraftScheduler.mainThreadHeartbeat(CraftScheduler.java:391) [minecraft_server.jar:git-Spigot-518206a-a5b9c7b]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_13_R2.MinecraftServer.b(MinecraftServer.java:888) [minecraft_server.jar:git-Spigot-518206a-a5b9c7b]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_13_R2.DedicatedServer.b(DedicatedServer.java:417) [minecraft_server.jar:git-Spigot-518206a-a5b9c7b]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_13_R2.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:830) [minecraft_server.jar:git-Spigot-518206a-a5b9c7b]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_13_R2.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:728) [minecraft_server.jar:git-Spigot-518206a-a5b9c7b]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_191]
>[14:52:07 INFO]: [WorldGuard] Enabling WorldGuard v7.0.0-beta-03;e51a220
>[14:52:07 INFO]: [WorldGuard] (world) TNT ignition is PERMITTED.
>[14:52:07 INFO]: [WorldGuard] (world) Lighters are PERMITTED.
>[14:52:07 INFO]: [WorldGuard] (world) Lava fire is blocked.
>[14:52:07 INFO]: [WorldGuard] (world) Fire spread is UNRESTRICTED.
>[14:52:07 INFO]: [WorldGuard] Loaded configuration for world 'world'
>[14:52:07 INFO]: [WorldGuard] (world_nether) TNT ignition is PERMITTED.
>[14:52:07 INFO]: [WorldGuard] (world_nether) Lighters are PERMITTED.
>[14:52:07 INFO]: [WorldGuard] (world_nether) Lava fire is blocked.
>[14:52:07 INFO]: [WorldGuard] (world_nether) Fire spread is UNRESTRICTED.
>[14:52:07 INFO]: [WorldGuard] Loaded configuration for world 'world_nether'
>[14:52:07 INFO]: [WorldGuard] (world_the_end) TNT ignition is PERMITTED.
>[14:52:07 INFO]: [WorldGuard] (world_the_end) Lighters are PERMITTED.
>[14:52:07 INFO]: [WorldGuard] (world_the_end) Lava fire is blocked.
>[14:52:07 INFO]: [WorldGuard] (world_the_end) Fire spread is UNRESTRICTED.
>[14:52:07 INFO]: [WorldGuard] Loaded configuration for world 'world_the_end'
>[14:52:08 INFO]: [WorldGuard] Loading region data...
>[14:52:08 INFO]: [Factions] Enabling Factions v2.14.0
>[14:52:08 INFO]: [Factions 2.14.0] === ENABLE START ===
>[14:52:08 INFO]: [ClearLag] No updates found!
>[14:52:08 INFO]: [Factions 2.14.0] Integration Activated IntegrationV18
>[14:52:08 INFO]: [Factions 2.14.0] Integration Activated IntegrationV19
>[14:52:08 INFO]: [Factions 2.14.0] Integration Activated IntegrationSpigot
>[14:52:08 INFO]: [Factions 2.14.0] === ENABLE COMPLETE (Took 812ms) ===
>[14:52:08 INFO]: [EssentialsXMPP] Enabling EssentialsXMPP v2.16.1.0
>[14:52:08 WARN]: config broken for xmpp
>[14:52:08 INFO]: [EssentialsProtect] Enabling EssentialsProtect v2.16.1.0
>[14:52:08 INFO]: [EssentialsProtect] Continuing to enable Protect.
>[14:52:08 INFO]: [Dynmap-Factions] Enabling Dynmap-Factions v0.90-39
[14:53:12 INFO]: Unknown command. Type "/help" for help.
[14:53:12 INFO]: Unknown command. Type "/help" for help.
[14:53:12 INFO]: Unknown command. Type "/help" for help.
[14:53:12 INFO]: Unknown command. Type "/help" for help.
[14:53:12 INFO]: Unknown command. Type "/help" for help.
[14:53:12 INFO]: Unknown command. Type "/help" for help.
[14:53:12 INFO]: Unknown command. Type "/help" for help.
>[14:52:08 INFO]: [Dynmap-Factions] initializing
[14:53:12 INFO]: Unknown command. Type "/help" for help.
[14:53:12 INFO]: Unknown command. Type "/help" for help.
[14:53:12 INFO]: Unknown command. Type "/help" for help.
[14:53:12 INFO]: Unknown command. Type "/help" for help.
[14:53:12 INFO]: Unknown command. Type "/help" for help.
[14:53:12 INFO]: Unknown command. Type "/help" for help.
[14:53:12 INFO]: Unknown command. Type "/help" for help.
[14:53:12 INFO]: Unknown command. Type "/help" for help.
[14:53:12 INFO]: Unknown command. Type "/help" for help.
[14:53:12 INFO]: Unknown command. Type "/help" for help.
[14:53:12 INFO]: Unknown command. Type "/help" for help.
[14:53:12 INFO]: Unknown command. Type "/help" for help.
[14:53:12 INFO]: Unknown command. Type "/help" for help.
[14:53:12 INFO]: Unknown command. Type "/help" for help.
[14:53:12 INFO]: Unknown command. Type "/help" for help.
[14:53:12 INFO]: Unknown command. Type "/help" for help.
[14:53:12 INFO]: Unknown command. Type "/help" for help.
[14:53:12 INFO]: Unknown command. Type "/help" for help.
[14:53:12 INFO]: Unknown command. Type "/help" for help.
[14:53:12 INFO]: Unknown command. Type "/help" for help.
[14:53:12 INFO]: Unknown command. Type "/help" for help.
[14:53:12 INFO]: Unknown command. Type "/help" for help.
[14:53:12 INFO]: Unknown command. Type "/help" for help.
>[14:52:08 INFO]: [Dynmap-Factions] Dynmap does not have player-info-protected en                      abled - visibility-by-faction will have no effect
>[14:52:08 INFO]: [Dynmap-Factions] version 0.90-39 is activated
>[14:52:08 INFO]: Server permissions file permissions.yml is empty, ignoring it
>[14:52:09 INFO]: Done (7.983s)! For help, type "help"
>[14:52:10 INFO]: [dynmap] Loading default resource pack
>[14:52:11 WARN]: [Dynmap-Factions] Task #44 for Dynmap-Factions v0.90-39 generat                      ed an exception
>java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>        at java.lang.String.replace(String.java:2240) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
>        at org.dynmap.factions.DynmapFactionsPlugin.formatInfoWindow(DynmapFacti                      onsPlugin.java:207) ~[?:?]
>        at org.dynmap.factions.DynmapFactionsPlugin.handleFactionOnWorld(DynmapF                      actionsPlugin.java:312) ~[?:?]
>        at org.dynmap.factions.DynmapFactionsPlugin.updateFactions(DynmapFaction                      sPlugin.java:507) ~[?:?]
>        at org.dynmap.factions.DynmapFactionsPlugin.access$000(DynmapFactionsPlu                      gin.java:49) ~[?:?]
>        at org.dynmap.factions.DynmapFactionsPlugin$FactionsUpdate.run(DynmapFac                      tionsPlugin.java:133) ~[?:?]
>        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_13_R2.scheduler.CraftTask.run(CraftTask.jav                      a:81) ~[minecraft_server.jar:git-Spigot-518206a-a5b9c7b]
>        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_13_R2.scheduler.CraftScheduler.mainThreadHe                      artbeat(CraftScheduler.java:391) [minecraft_server.jar:git-Spigot-518206a-a5b9c7                      b]
>        at net.minecraft.server.v1_13_R2.MinecraftServer.b(MinecraftServer.java:                      888) [minecraft_server.jar:git-Spigot-518206a-a5b9c7b]
>        at net.minecraft.server.v1_13_R2.DedicatedServer.b(DedicatedServer.java:                      417) [minecraft_server.jar:git-Spigot-518206a-a5b9c7b]
>        at net.minecraft.server.v1_13_R2.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:                      830) [minecraft_server.jar:git-Spigot-518206a-a5b9c7b]
>        at net.minecraft.server.v1_13_R2.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.jav                      a:728) [minecraft_server.jar:git-Spigot-518206a-a5b9c7b]
>        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_191]
```

Comment: Did you program this `Dynmap-Factions` by yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Dynmap-Factions hooks into the pre-1.13 versions of WorldGuard due to their deployment system grabbing the wrong version. You need to compile from source yourself to get this working.